# How to increment a value by 1 when insert with laravel using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel Eloquent method to insert data to table, I want to increment invoice_no when user is admin, how can i achieve this with laravel Eloquent

```
$user = $request->input('user');
$add_order = new AddOrder;
if($user=="admin")
{
   $add_order->invoice_no = 0;
   //$add_order->invoice_no = "latest invoice_no in database + 1"
}
$add_order->invoice_prefix = 'NGW';
$add_order->store_name = 'Test Store';
$save_order = $add_order->save();
```

Comment: do you have admin in your user model?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this.

```
    $user               =   $request->input('user');
    $add_order         =    new AddOrder;
    $latestAddOrder     =   $add_order->latest()->first();
    if($user=="admin"){
       $add_order->invoice_no = $latestAddOrder->invoice_no + 1;
    }
    $add_order->invoice_prefix  = 'NGW';
    $add_order->store_name      = 'Test Store';
    $save_order = $add_order->save();
```

Here, I retrieved last row from the database.